# Is it possible to send a caption/annotation to Instagram via its custom URL scheme from Mobile Safari?

Tags: mobile, mobile-safari, instagram

I'd like to allow users of my mobile website to upload a photo, enter a tag and caption in Mobile Safari, then open Instagram with that image, tag and caption pre-populated.

Based on [this](http://instagram.com/developer/iphone-hooks/) documentation, it's possible to pre-populate the image and tag, but the only mention of pre-populating a caption is "To include a pre-filled caption with your photo, you can set the annotation property on the document interaction request to an NSDictionary containing an NSString under the key "InstagramCaption."

Can I use a custom URL, something like: `instagram://media?id=999&tag?name=sweet_tag&InstagramCaption?caption='My sweet caption.'` to pre-populate an image, tag and caption?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This feature does exist, it just hasn't been added to the documentation yet.

> Starting with our next release (2.3.0) you'll be able to pass in a
>   caption parameter to the camera URL hook, like so:
>
> instagram://camera?caption=hello
>
> Make sure it's properly URL-encoded (# should be %23, etc)
>
> Submitted to Apple, so should be out in the near future.
>
> Cheers,
>   --  Mike Krieger Co-founder, Instagram

https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/instagram-api-developers/0lsJyFcfYPw