# How to pass a longer caption, with spaces, via "instagram://camera?caption"?

Tags: instagram

Is it possible to pass a longer caption through the camera or is it limited to one word?

I've seen this example:

```
instagram://camera?caption=hello
```

But could I use something like this?

```
instagram://camera?caption=hello%20world
```

Comment: What happens when you try it?

Comment: I'm sorry, to be honest I don't even know how. I'm working with a vendor who has said this isn't possible, but I've only been able to talk to a sales person not the actual engineer. I'm trying to research it on my own so I have something to go back to them with. Sorry if this was the wrong forum for this, thanks for your time!

Comment: Are you using the API?

Comment: Yes to launch the app at the camera stage and then (hopefully) pre-populate a caption

Comment: Do you have a link to documentation for the `camera` call?

Comment: This is all I've been able to find: http://instagram.com/developer/iphone-hooks/

Comment: Have you been able to get `instagram://camera?caption=hello` to work?  If so, then try `instagram://camera?caption=hello%20world` in the same way.

Comment: Based on the link from the answer of @AdmiralAdama, seems like `%20` would work just as well as `%23`, which is the substitute for `#`.

Answer (score 1):

Yes this should work fine for you.

The documentation hasn't really been published very well but you can see here for people [URL encoding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12586775/is-it-possible-to-send-a-caption-annotation-to-instagram-via-its-custom-url-sche)